# Does Heroku rolls back every day?

Tags: heroku

I am a newbie, I just deployed app which is similar to shopping website where user can add products to favorites and pick a pick-up date and put in an order.
However, the products that I added to favorite and orders that I put in are gone when I open the website next day. How can I save all the changes that I make and orders that I created in the website?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How are you saving that data? Into a JSON file? An SQLite database? Something else?

Comment: SQLite database

Comment: @BKBK That's not gonna work, then. It gets reset at least once daily.